# Why both 0 and NULL mean empty in PHP?

Tags: php, function

Take a look at this:

```
$var1 = 0;
$var2 = '0';
$var3 = null;

If (empty($var1)) { echo 'it is empty'; }  // output: it is empty
If (empty($var2)) { echo 'it is empty'; }  // output: it is empty
If (empty($var3)) { echo 'it is empty'; }  // output: it is empty
```

As you see, PHP thinks all three above variables are empty ..! Now I want to know, how can I check `$_GET['arg']` is `0` or nothing?

---

```
/* www.example.com?arg1=0&arg2= */
```

I need to detect `arg1` is zero and `arg2` is empty, How can I do that?

Comment: Check the [identity operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php). Also, if you would check the [empty function manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php), you wouldn't be surprised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://php.net/empty

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

"Equals" false here means `==`, so NULL, 0, '0', etc. all are considered to be false-y for its purposes.

[image]

You can use `is_null` or strict comparison with `===`.

```
if($foo === null) { echo "it's null"; }
if(is_null($foo)) { echo "it's null"; }
```

Answer (score 2):

You should explicitly check for null like this:

```
If ($var3 === null) { echo 'it is empty'; }
```

Comment: `==` will evaluate true on 0 here.